# Android - jmdns doesn't discover devices

Tags: android, android-annotations, jmdns, mdns, android-nsd

I'm trying to implement a class to discover services on the network.
I've tried working with [Android's NSD](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) and it does discover the services fine, but it supports only API levels 16 and up, and I can't seem to retrieve the txtRecord field within the service info (it returns null for some reason). Turns out [it's a known problem...](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35810)

So now I'm trying to work with [jmDNS](https://github.com/jmdns/jmdns), which doesn't seem to find services at all.
here's my class (I'm working with the AndroidAnnotations framework) MDnsHelper:

```
@EBean
public class MDnsHelper implements ServiceListener {

public static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp.local";

Activity activity;
private JmDNS jmdns;
private MulticastLock multicastLock;
WifiManager wm;
InetAddress bindingAddress;
boolean isDiscovering;

public void init(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    isDiscovering = false;
    wm = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    multicastLock = wm.createMulticastLock(activity.getPackageName());
    multicastLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
}

@Background
public void startDiscovery() {
    if (isDiscovering)
        return;
    System.out.println("starting...");
    multicastLock.acquire();
    try {
        System.out.println("creating jmdns");
        jmdns = JmDNS.create();
        System.out.println("jmdns created");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (jmdns != null) {
            jmdns.addServiceListener(SERVICE_TYPE, MDnsHelper.this);
            isDiscovering = true;
            System.out.println("discovering services of type: " + SERVICE_TYPE);
        }
    }
}

@Background
public void stopDiscovery() {
    if (!isDiscovering || jmdns == null)
        return;
    System.out.println("stopping...");
    multicastLock.release();
    jmdns.removeServiceListener(SERVICE_TYPE, MDnsHelper.this);
    System.out.println("listener for " + SERVICE_TYPE + " removed");
    try {
        jmdns.close();
        isDiscovering = false;
        System.out.println("jmdns closed");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent service) {
    System.out.println("found: " + service.getInfo().toString());
}

@Override
public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent service) {
    System.out.println("lost: " + service.getInfo().toString());
}

@Override
public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent service) {
    System.out.println("resolved: " + service.getInfo().toString());
}
}
```

And in my app I call:

```
init(getActivity());
```

And then `startDiscovery();` to start scanning and `stopDiscovery();` to stop scanning.

And of course, I gave the app the required permissions in the manifest...
What am I missing here?
If you need me to provide additional code/info - just ask.
thanks!!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I am the author of ZeroConf Browser for Android and I use the open source Library JmDNS for all my resolving. It works great but there are a few tricks to getting it to work properly.

1. In your Android manifest.xml make sure you have these permissions at least.

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
   ```
2. Before starting the activity you must allow multi-cast packets by acquiring a multicast lock.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       Log.i(TAG, "Starting ServiceActivity...");
       super.onStart();
       try {
           Log.i(TAG, "Starting Mutlicast Lock...");
           WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
           // get the device ip address
           final InetAddress deviceIpAddress = getDeviceIpAddress(wifi);
           multicastLock = wifi.createMulticastLock(getClass().getName());
           multicastLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
           multicastLock.acquire();
           Log.i(TAG, "Starting ZeroConf probe....");
           jmdns = JmDNS.create(deviceIpAddress, HOSTNAME);
           jmdns.addServiceTypeListener(this);
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
       }
       Log.i(TAG, "Started ZeroConf probe....");
   }

   private InetAddress getDeviceIpAddress(WifiManager wifi) {
      InetAddress result = null;
      try {
         // default to Android localhost
         result = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.2");

         // figure out our wifi address, otherwise bail
         WifiInfo wifiinfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
         int intaddr = wifiinfo.getIpAddress();
         byte[] byteaddr = new byte[] { (byte) (intaddr & 0xff), (byte) (intaddr >> 8 & 0xff),
             (byte) (intaddr >> 16 & 0xff), (byte) (intaddr >> 24 & 0xff) };
         result = InetAddress.getByAddress(byteaddr);
      } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
         Log.w(TAG, String.format("getDeviceIpAddress Error: %s", ex.getMessage()));
      }

      return result;
   }
   ```
3. And don't forget on stopping the scan to unlock the multicast lock and shut down JmDNS.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       Log.i(TAG, "Stopping ServiceActivity...");
       super.onStop();

       stopScan();
   }

   private static void stopScan() {
       try {
           if (jmdns != null) {
               Log.i(TAG, "Stopping ZeroConf probe....");
               jmdns.unregisterAllServices();
               jmdns.close();
               jmdns = null;
           }
           if (multicastLock != null) {
               Log.i(TAG, "Releasing Mutlicast Lock...");
               multicastLock.release();
               multicastLock = null;
           }
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Most importanty don't use the default constructor.  You must use the IP Address Constructor.  I noticed in your code you are just doing JmDNS.create().  I think for some reason the only way it works on Android is to use the contructor below.

   ```
   jmdns = JmDNS.create(deviceIpAddress, HOSTNAME);
   ```

Comment: Works! Turns out I used the wrong constructor, so bullet 4 was what solved it. Thanks a million!! :)

Comment: One thing that kill me is how can one quickly find devices in the local network with some many service types being available. Your browser is fast! Can you give a hint on how you do it? I'm working on a remote control for IoT devices and need to know anything that lives on the local network fast (and get device info in the process)

Comment: So are you saying your code is not finding the services fast enough by my ZeroConf Browser app is?   All I am using is the above code so theoretically yours should be as fast as mine?

Comment: On the contrary I'm saying yours is much faster than mine!! Because I loop through a huge list of services (slow). So please, just as a general tip, how do you find so many services in a short time? Do you have a list of services to search for? jmDNS finds all services already? All the examples I see show how to connect to a specific service. But I want to see the "menu" of available services on the local network :)

Comment: Nevermind. I wasn't using jmdns right. I was taking the services from my own big list and not subscribing to service type changes (now it all makes sense). Thx anyway!

Comment: @Melloware : I need to get the details of all wireless devices (not just android mobiles) that are connected to my wifi network. like, IP, MAC addresses, vendor-name, device type (i.e laptop, mobile, AC, Refrigerator) and host names. Can I use jmDNS/ZerConf for my need?

Comment: @SANTHOSH No you cannot. This is only for discovering services exposed by Bonjour.  Not a general network scanner which is what I think you are looking for.

Comment: @Melloware : What serves my requirement? Could you please suggest me? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567725/how-do-i-get-host-names-by-using-ip-mac-addresses-in-android

Comment: Where is `getDeviceIpAddress()`?

Comment: @emc I just edited the post to add the getDeviceIpAddress() method.

Comment: @Melloware Late to the party but what would be wrong with a call to InetAddress.getLocalHost() to determine the local IP address? Not guaranteed to be the wifi interface?

Comment: @JoeHz you can try it as you can see this post is 5 years old now but the only reliable way I could get the IP to properly resolve for all cases was using the above trick.  I remember their being some quirks on old Android versions with getLocalHost().  You can definitely try it though!

Comment: @melloware, shouldn't this excellent "tutorial" become that; a tutorial for using jmdns for Android? Just spent a day pondering as the code works on Windows, but not on Android. I am sure it will after this. Thanks!

Comment: @carl yeah it should I just need time to blog post somewhere.  Usually I just point people here. :0

Comment: @melloware. As assumed it worked. Please do put one line with a link in the GitHub readme pointing here for (future) Android users.

Comment: @carl do you mean in the JMDNS Github?   I am not a committer there so all I could do is suggest it.

Comment: @melloware, Ok. Thought you were, but suggest is a good alternative, yes

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this error in **Android Oreo 8.x**, this might help you.

First, Remember to make sure you have added these permissions into your Android `manifest.xml`.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

Acquire a multicast lock to allow multi-cast packets.

```java
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
MulticastLock lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("jmdns-multicast-lock");
lock.setReferenceCounted(true);
lock.acquire();
```

Now, use only this constructor `JmDNS.create(InetAddress addr, String name)` to create an instance of **JmDNS** and bind it to a specific network interface given its IP-address, like this:

```java
try {
    jmDNS = JmDNS.create(InetAddress.getByName(obtainIPv4Address(info)), HOST_NAME);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LogHelper.e(TAG, "Error in JmDNS creation: " + e);
}
```

Finally, just make sure to call `JmDNSunreisterAllServices()`, and `JmDNS.close()` to stop JmDNS stream and releases any system resources associated with it. Also, call `MulticastLock.release()` to unlock the multicast lock when you're done with it.

```java
try {
    if (jmDNS != null) {
        jmDNS.unregisterAllServices();
        jmDNS.close();
        jmDNS = null;
    }
    if (lock != null) {
        lock.release();
        lock = null;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The obtainIPv4Address() must be a local method of yours @Teocci, but replacing that, and following your outline with a teaspoon (already had it), it does not work on Android 8, but on Android 7. I think we have a problem. Could it be something in the security setting of Android 8? I use LG V30.